# How to get location of the caller when get a call in android

Tags: android, mobile, location

Is it possible to get location of the caller when get a call? If so provide some links to achieve it. Thanks in advance..

Edit: OR else how to get at-least approximate location or lastly State name of the incoming number.

Answer (score 1):

No.  That data isn't carried over the phone call in the metadata, and there's no data connection in a phone call.  Nor does it make sense for it to be sent-  that['s a security nightmare.  How would you like it if your worst enemy could find out where you are at any time just by calling you?  Or a pedo could find a child's location by calling their phone?  Or a rapist a woman's location by calling her?  It's a bad idea.  If you want to share your location with someone there's a variety of apps that do that, and just about all of them allow you to restrict that knowledge so you have some security.  Use them instead.

Comment: How can I retrieve SIM network and State (Ex. Andhra Pradesh) of the location of mobile number in android but not the exact location.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the exact location of a caller in mobile networks is theoretically impossible, due to the architecture of mobile networks.
Briefly speaking, Mobile networks divide land areas into "Hives", which determines a closed ploygon. The shape of the polygon is normally a hexagon which is adjacent to other hexagons. These hexagons are covered by BTS towers, which are responsible for responding to call requests, routing and call hand-over.
Some but not all providers enable their BTS to report their GPS coordinates and the database of all these coordinates is some kind of confidential data.
Again some but not all providers, make their databse of BTS towers available , which depends on the host country regulations and the provider company policies.
However there are databases on the web, which gather this coordinates of different providers but since the data is not gathered or distributed in an online and timely fashion, there may be complications, let alone the web service you need to use for querying which normally is not provided.
But since I assume you're in India, [you may find this website useful.](http://indiatrace.com/trace-mobile-number-location/trace-mobile-number.php)

**EDIT**
After googling , I found these websites that provide Cell-ID databses.

**https://unwiredlabs.com/[2](http://unwiredlabs.com/)

http://location-api.com/

http://www.opencellid.org/

https://wigle.net/

http://cellspotting.com/webpages/cellspotting.html

http://www.cellmapper.net/

http://www.opencelldb.net/**

Comment: By using this http://www.indiatrace.com/trace-mobile-number-location/trace-mobile-number.php link how can I retrieve state of that location in android like as it showing now.

Comment: I think you should contact them to see if they let you access via a webservice or sth. As I see , a webservice or developer API is not provided on their website. Proceed to contact other links too.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Please send me if you got any related API's to achieve  this.

Comment: glad I could help. I'll let you know if anything new came up.just mark the answer as accepted if you think it solves your problem.

Comment: It is not solved my problem yet, so that is why I up voted it.